# Python 2 to 3 - slower thread execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.x, python-3.7

Can someone tell me if the threading was slowed from Python 2 to Python 3? I'm currently converting my Python 2 software to Python 3, and now it is all laggy due to the fact that I have simultaneous threads.

My software basically acquires data, displays it and saves it to a file. I start doing this in a given thread A. Thread A then starts an acquisition using a thread B (which receives data through a callback from an API, every 1ms, and puts it in a queue; all in Thread B), and a file-writing thread C (which receives data through a queue). Furthermore, Thread A (after starting Threads B and C) also has a loop which continuously gets gata from the data queue and sends it for display.

So I've noticed that if I don't start the file-writing thread, my code is fast as an eagle. However, when I initialise it, it gets slow as a turtle (for example, the callback from the API which receives data, gets data only every 100ms or so). This code was fast with Python 2 but now in Python 3 is slow, without changing anything from my code. Any clue on how to fix this?

PS. I don't use any asyncio stuff in here. I'm using threading.Thread to initialise my threads.

Comment: Describing code isn't nearly as useful as showing it to us. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi Chris! Unfortunately not - I know it's a bummer. I've tried to reproduce it but with no luck